# What was this post deleted and no reason given?

Tags: discussion

## What was this post deleted and no reason given?

**Here is the original question:**
[Is Kurt Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem a "cheap trick"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/210/is-kurt-g%c3%b6dels-incompleteness-theorem-a-cheap-trick)

## "We are therefore confronted with a proposition which asserts its own unprovability." (Gödel 1931:39-41)

If we take the simplest possible essence of Gödel's logic sentence we have:
**G asserts its own unprovability in F**.

This means that G is asserting that there is no sequence of inference steps in F that derives G.

**For G to be proved in F requires a sequence of inference steps in F that proves there is no such sequence of inference steps in F.**

This is like René Descartes saying:
 **“I think therefore thoughts do not exist”**

**Gödel knew about this contradiction:**
..."there is also a close relationship with the “liar” antinomy,14" (Gödel 1931:39-41)

"14 Every epistemological antinomy can likewise be used for a similar undecidability proof."(Gödel 1931:39-41)

Arithmetization and diagonalization hide the reason ***why*** G is unprovable in F and merely report ***that*** G is unprovable in F.

The proof of G in F requires a sequence of inference steps in F that proves there is no such sequence of inference steps in F. **This means that G cannot be proved in F because its proof is contradictory not that F is incomplete.**

**Gödel, Kurt 1931.**
On Formally Undecidable Propositions of Principia Mathematica And Related Systems

Answer (score 1):

Even if it had a valid point, which I am still skeptical about, it completely misses what the question asked for and thus falls under the "not an answer to the question" case, which it was flagged for as well. The deletion was the automatic consequence of an approval of that flag (disclaimer: It was not I who handled the flag).

The reason for that not being an answer is that you are pushing a point of your own and thereby completely miss that *even if parts of your answer are correct*, the result of the theorem still stands *because that is how these concepts, formally, are defined*. You cannot simply state that the theorem was not about incompleteness. It rather points out something really problematic within the relations between provability and completeness.

These problems do not magically disappear by shifting goalposts, taking different wordings and definitions for granted, and thereby dismissing the importance of the theorem altogether. Alas, this is what you consistently do in various ways *because that is what your goal is*.

That is not how science or philosophy work well. You do not pursue a goal because that will enhance the influence of cognitive biases. One can read any answer of yours and immediately see that this is not about the context of the question but your agenda.

Comment: Let's start with this: Assuming that  G asserts its own unprovability in F: Do you understand that a proof of G in F requires a sequence of inference steps in F that proves that no such sequence of inference steps exists in F?

Comment: Do not argue with me about a formal proof in natural language to begin with. Do not argue with me about something generations of mathematicians way smarter than both of us combined accepted as valid as well. And last but not least, nothing of this invalidates my argumentation as made in this post.

Comment: In other words you are dodging my question because you simply don't understand that when G asserts its own unprovability in F that this requires a sequence of inference steps in F that proves no such sequence of inference steps exists in F. Gödel understood this and that is why he proved G in Meta-F.

Comment: Meta-F hides the reason WHY G is unprovable in F and only shows THAT G is unprovable in F through arithmetization and diagonalization. When we assume a much more powerful F that doesn't need arithmetization or diagonalization, then and only then we see WHY G remains unprovable even in this much more powerful F.

Comment: Gödel even explictly acknowledges that the reason that G cannot be proved in F is that the proof of G is contradictory in F: 

"14 Every epistemological antinomy can likewise be used for a similar undecidability proof." (Gödel 1931:39-41)

Gödel, Kurt 1931.
On Formally Undecidable Propositions of Principia Mathematica And Related Systems

Comment: **The conclusion that F is "incomplete" has the false assumption that formal systems are supposed to be able to prove contradictions.**  This false assumption derives Gödel's false conclusion thus invalidating his whole proof even if every other step of the proof is correct.

Comment: You are the one not understanding a simple fact here: The framework of any sufficiently complex formal arithmetic language is such that any well-formed formula that is an antinomy - and those are explicitly well-formed according to the rules of these frameworks - can be used to show their incompleteness. That is what Gödel says there. **And that is an important and meaningful feature of these arithmetic languages that is important to see, prove, and acknowledge.** That is what Gödel became famous for. And that is also the reason why I say that what you say is completely missing the point.

Comment: The mistake here is assuming that a syntactically well-formed expression of language is sufficiently well-formed without bothering to verify that it is semantically coherent. Self-contradictory expressions are not semantically coherent thus are not even truth bearers. The domain (universe of discourse) of formal systems is the set of truth bearers that can be expressed in language L. **Ignoring this restriction is the simple oversight that enables undecidability and incompleteness to exist.**

Comment: @polcott You argue from what you think things should be like. The reality of formal languages and these concepts is different. That is why all your arguments are null and void. If your premise is "that is how things should be like", the conclusion trivially will be that this indeed is the case. Circular arguments lack soundness, though.

Comment: In mathematical logic, a sentence (or closed formula)[1] of a predicate logic is a Boolean-valued well-formed formula with no free variables. A sentence can be viewed as expressing a proposition, ***something that must be true or false.***  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(mathematical_logic)

The above is saying the essentially same thing that I said that formal systems only include truth bearers.

Comment: "You argue from what you think things should be like." There is a certain way that correct reasoning really works. When mathematical systems model this incorrectly they diverge from correct reasoning. People that only learn things by rote never notice the incoherence because they make sure to never look for it.

Comment: @polcott There is no such thing as "a certain way that correct reasoning really works". There is the losely conventional, plastic way natural languages work with implicit, grown rules and the goal of transmitting meaning and there is the rigid, formal way of formal languages that can make rules to their liking with various consequences out of applying these rules. Gödel made one of the consequences for one class of the latter explicit. You want to mix normative, meta-linguistic ideas into formal and natural languages alike, ideas from a time before that divide actually took place.

Comment: The problem is that you do not discuss the advantages **and caveats** that come with this, nor can you tell people how to use language "properly". Language is a tool for communication of content, not something that has to comply with your ideas of how it should look like.

Comment: The key to correct reasoning is understanding that the entire body of analytical truth is a simply set of semantic tautologies, thus when formal logic systems diverge from this basis they diverge from correct reasoning. The benefits of correct reasoning are that we can mathematically formalize a True(X,L) predicate thus create automated systems that can take on each individual social media user and refute dangerous disinformation every which way before anyone comes to believe it.

Comment: @polcott You want every well-formed formula to have a *definite and provable* truth value. I get that. Most mathematicians disagree that this is necessary or even useful as it significantly reduces the power and ability to produce useful theorems and applications of languages limited in that way. Making the jump to natural languages even runs contrary to everything we came to know about natural languages in the last 80 or so years. Just stop it. You cannot just go back to 1920 and pretend everything after logical positivism was misguided nonsense.

Comment: **G asserts its own unprovability in F has been formalized using conventional symbolic logic: ∃G ∈ F (G ↔ (F ⊬ G))** Preliminary review indicates that it does correctly prove that there is no such G in F as opposed to and contrast with F is incomplete.

Comment: @polcott You happily jump between different frameworks and try to pretend that because you showed something in one of them it automatically carries over to the other one. From PA (or F) to conventional symbolic language, to C++, to whatever. You do not realise that showing something in one framework means *absolutely nothing* if you cannot do the same in the other framework, do you? And now I suggest you stop pinging me. I have said everything there is to say on the matter. Multiple times.

Comment: You still perpetually dodged my original question indicating that you do not understand that a proof of G in F would require a set of inference steps in F that prove that no such set of inference steps exists in F. An analogous question would be do you understand why you cannot correctly prove that you yourself never existed? ***This is the only point in our discussion that I ever wanted fully addressed***

Comment: @polcott And again, your statements are shifting goalposts since that was never asked for. A proof of G does not require "a set of inference steps in F that prove that *no such set of inference steps exists in F*" but "a finite set of inference steps in F that prove that *no finite set of inference steps exists that suffices to prove G in F*". That is an important difference. Again, you casually changed the point and argue about it as if it was the same.

Comment: Your version is an improvement only by explicitly stating that it must be a finite set of inference steps. It is less accurate  because it fails make the required epistemological antinomy clear. 

"14 Every epistemological antinomy can likewise be used for a similar undecidability proof." (Gödel 1931:39-41)

Because G asserts its own unprovability in F a proof of G in F requires a finite sequence of inference steps in F that proves no such sequence of inference steps exists in F.

**Gödel, Kurt 1931** On Formally Undecidable Propositions of Principia Mathematica And Related Systems

Answer (score -1):

## Reply to answer

In other words you are dodging my question because you simply don't understand that when G asserts its own unprovability in F that this requires a sequence of inference steps in F that proves no such sequence of inference steps exists in F. Gödel understood this and that is why he proved G in Meta-F.

Meta-F hides the reason WHY G is unprovable in F and only shows THAT G is unprovable in F through arithmetization and diagonalization. When we assume a much more powerful F that doesn't need arithmetization or diagonalization, then and only then we see WHY G remains unprovable even in this much more powerful F.

Gödel even explicitly acknowledges that the reason that G cannot be proved in F is that the proof of G is contradictory in F:

"14 Every epistemological antinomy can likewise be used for a similar undecidability proof." (Gödel 1931:39-41)

**Gödel, Kurt 1931.** On Formally Undecidable Propositions of Principia Mathematica And Related Systems –

The conclusion that F is "incomplete" has the false assumption that formal systems are supposed to be able to prove contradictions. This false assumption derives Gödel's false conclusion thus invalidating his whole proof even if every other step of the proof is correct.

The mistake here is assuming that a syntactically well-formed expression of language is sufficiently well-formed without bothering to verify that it is semantically coherent. Self-contradictory expressions are not semantically coherent thus are not even truth bearers.

The domain (universe of discourse) of formal systems is the set of truth bearers that can be expressed in language L. Ignoring this restriction is the simple oversight that enables undecidability and incompleteness to exist.